# Error when uploading UWP app to Windows Store: Failed to merge PRI file \Resources_split.scale-100.pri

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-store

I am uploading a latest version of my app to the Windows store but my app is throwing the error:

> Package acceptance validation error: We encountered a fatal error
>   while parsing the package
>   MyApp.UWP_2.33.0.0_x86_x64_ARM_AppStore.appxbundle: Failed
>   to merge PRI file
>   D:\data\Temp\69b5c2ab-3419-4197-839c-2ef13d218413\Resources_split.scale-100.pri:
>   80070490. Try again or upload a new package.

I do not understand where to even begin to look to fix this error.

has anyone else seen this error or have any inclin to what it may be?

This is also throwing a similar error when running on The `Windows App Certification Kit` Attached is the screenshot below:

[image]

So far I have tried:

- Running WsReset
- Running sfc /scannow
- Increasing Version number of app

none of the above have worked

Could it be this msbuild error: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/107928/get-merge-failure-for-shared-merged-pri-file-0x800.html?

Comment: This failed on a low-level OS error, 0x80070490 == ERROR_NO_MORE_USER_HANDLES == "The current process has used all of its system allowance of handles for Window Manager objects".  It is the kind of mishap that tends to so often strike Microsoft servers over a holiday weekend when nobody is around to tend to them.  Just wait a day or two, reboot your machine on the low odds that this came from your end, and try again.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for that extra information. I will open a support ticket when they open today, I will also try reboot my build machine as suggested, to rule that out

Comment: @HansPassant I also get this same error when running the `Windows App Certification kit` on my local machine. I think this could be something wrong with the package not on Microsoft's side

Comment: Hmm, that's pretty odd, the error code is very specific and not unusual.  Use Task Manager, Processes tab.  Add the "User Objects" column.  Look for processes that have entirely too many of them, thousands.  Reboot if you see them.  If none then observe WACK while it runs, it would keel over with this error when the count reaches 10000.

Comment: @HansPassant Building on my machine (not my build machine) didn't throw the error with the `App Cert Kit`. This means the issue must be my build machine is creating a corrupt package. Either a windows update on that machine or the fact on my machine i built through VS and build machine uses msbuild. I will try what you said above

Comment: It could be a build machine artifact if it builds using a service and you'd also run WACK and try to upload using that same service.  Services run in a separate session that has a very small desktop heap.

Comment: @HansPassant Uploaded the WACK error from my Build machine if youre interrested. May give a bit more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround I have found is to get rid of the ARM configuration.

So you build with just `x86|x64` instead of `x86|x64|ARM` obviously this doesn't help if you need to build for `ARM`

But I think this is a bug in a recent update to MsBuild which you can see reported by other people here:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/107928/get-merge-failure-for-shared-merged-pri-file-0x800.html?

Answer (score 0):

I had almost this exact error happening to me. After digging though a month of previous commits I came across this in my csproj.

```
<GenerateLibraryLayout>true</GenerateLibraryLayout>
```

Wasn't sure when I turned that on but after I deleted that line, I repackaged my code and was able to upload my appxbundle to the windows store. Pretty frustrating how misleading the error was.

Answer (score 0):

I also had issues with similar error and disabling ARM and tweaking .csproj options did not help.

What did the trick for us unbundling, bundling and resigning the package.
This was input from Microsoft support team after months of "communication".

Basically we unzipped .appxupload file and performed following commands on .appxbundle file.

```
makeappx.exe unbundle /v /p <<NAME>>.appxbundle /d "temp"
makeappx.exe bundle /v /p <<NAME>>_rebundled.appxbundle /d "temp"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.18362.0\x64\signtool.exe" sign /fd SHA256 /a /f "<<CERTIFICATE_LOCATION>>" <<NAME>>_rebundled.appxbundle
```

After this I zipped sym files and newly bundled .appxbundle to .appxupload file

Comment: How to unzip and zip `.msixupload` file?

Comment: Just using 7zip

Comment: And how did you use 7zip to convert the `.appxbundle` to an `.appxupload`? or in my case convert a `.msixbundle` to `.msixupload`. Did you use zip archive format and then just rename it? Also wondering what sym files you are referring to.

Comment: We never converted bundle file to upload file, as bundle filed is located inside of upload one.
In fact upload file is just a zip containing of one bundle file and one .appxsym file for each of configurations you are building for (these are similar to .pdb files in .NET Framework)
I basically just zipped those files and renamed the extension to .appxupload

Comment: Indeed,I can also just upload the `.msixbundle` which worked, thanks!

Comment: Did your app pass submission process as well?
Because we get the exact some error on submission. And I am still waiting for some support response on this issue.

Comment: Yes it did, new version is published in the store as well. I am also busy with support to get this fixed though.

Comment: Can you post z complete powershell script to perform all steps?