# Merge failure for shared merged PRI file: error 0x80070490. Fault in my computer?

Tags: uwp, app-bundle

I am installing an app(UWP) in my windows 10 an app that I have received from other developer( with a app-bundle or with powershell). This app was already installed in my computer. WHen I try to reinstall it I receive this error and I have no way to reinstall it. I have the doubt if is something wrong in my computer or is something wrong in the software compiled by the other developer

Merge failure for shared merged PRI file: error 0x80070490: no se puede registrar

> package FixMyRobot_1.0.0.0_x64__pzq3xp76mxafg merge error with
>   following file: C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsApps\FixMyRobot_1.0.0.0_neutral_split.scale-100_pzq3xp76mxafg\resources.pri

Answer (score 0):

It may be the developer's develop software's issue:
 [Error when uploading UWP app to Windows Store: Failed to merge PRI file \Resources_split.scale-100.pri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47507692/error-when-uploading-uwp-app-to-windows-store-failed-to-merge-pri-file-resourc?rq=1),

If the developer use Visual Studio, he can try to update to the latest version and package it again. Otherwise, you can also try to install it on other devices to see whether this issue still happens.