# Error merging pri files when submitting my app package

Tags: uwp, windows-store

i have the following Visual Studio solution

.NET Standard project (contains embedded resources)

UWP Library project (shared acros multiple apps)

UWP Excecutable Project

the UWP excecutable Project has a reference to both the 'UWP Library' and the '.NET Standard library'

the UWP Library Project has a reference to the '.NET Standard library'

when i submit the app to the app store i get the error: Failed to merge PRI file D:\data\Temp\27683aaf-f01d-4f70-ab3f-45a6f29deb13\Resources_split.language-nl.pri: 80070490

when i remove the 'UWP Library' reference from the UWP Executable project and compile and upload to the app store it actually works.

the issue is most likely happens that both the Library and Executable Project make a Resources.pri file from the same embedded resource in the .NET Project. when the compiler makes a package it sees that both the project have the same resources and merges/removes one.

now i'm thinking of the following

- is it possible to exclude/ignore resource compilation in the "UWP Library Project"?
- is it possible to have a UWP library in form of a "Shared Project"
- is it possible for ms to fix this?

Comment: See this similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47507692/error-when-uploading-uwp-app-to-windows-store-failed-to-merge-pri-file-resourc and have a try with the second answer. If you still have this issue, could your provide a simple sample to help us reproduce and test it?